# Free email provider that doesn't ask for a name

Tags: gratis, web-apps, email

### Requirements

- Free Indefinitely (i.e. Not a 30-day trial)
- Does not ask for full name (first & last)

### Preferred

- <s>Online</s> in-browser (no download required)

---

**NOTE**: Services that have no legal ramifications for inputting a false name are also acceptable. I'm aware that most services probably don't enforce these restrictions, but I'm feeling paranoid today.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending software, not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta post on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/185) I'm curious, though: You mentioned "online" as nice-to-have. What's an "offline mail provider"? If the mail service is offline, it doesn't make sense to me as you cannot reach/access it ;)

Comment: Are you looking for a temporary email address or just a permanent one that doesn't ask for a name?

Comment: @Izzy By "online" I meant "in browser" that doesn't require a download. I'll change it. Also, is there an SE sure in which this question would work?

Comment: @Izumi-reiLuLu a permanent one.

Comment: @FracturedRetina I'm afraid there is no SE site where this is on-topic. But to give you some better keywords to google the topic: ["anonymous web-mailer"](https://www.google.com/search?q=anonymous+web-mailer) would match your description. Wow. And that search hits right down to the bones :)

Answer (score 0):

<s>How about [hushmail.com](http://www.hushmail.com)? It is a free service that don't require any personal details and on top of that offers encryption and aliases.</s>

**edit**

My bad, apparently the service isn't as free as I remembered. But they have a mode that is free forever but it is limited to 25 mb of email storage so it is rather limited. If you opt for the free version you also don't have to give them a name.

Comment: It isn't free and asks for a name.